# Providing bank's information, do I use local or corporate address?

Tags: banking, withdrawal, bank-of-america

I am filling out a form for authorizing automatic withdrawals from a Bank of America account. It asks for the information I would expect like routing number/account number, but it also asks for the bank's address (city/state) and phone number.

Since I can pretty much walk into any Bank of America across the nation and get service, I was curious if I should put the corporate address and contact number, or just pick one that is closest to my location?

Comment: Are you telling your bank where to send the money, or are you telling a company how to get the money?

Comment: how to get the money

Comment: The question you asked was about authorizing withdrawals, not making deposits.  Can you please make your question more clear?

Comment: The fact is it doesn't make much difference; you're OK either way.

Answer (score 4):

I usually pick Corporate since I don't have a particular location that I'm familiar with.  I open most of my accounts online and walk into whichever branch is convenient.

To the best of my knowledge, the address is used to ensure they have the correct bank.  Perhaps if something goes horribly wrong with a transfer, they may send documents by mail, but they'd likely try the phone # first and Corporate could handle any documents pertaining to my account anyway (probably better than an arbitrary branch could, unless I was a frequent customer there)

For example, I would use

```
Bank of America
PO Box 25118
Tampa, FL 33622-5118
```

for Bank of America

This is also a common question (confirm city and state, sometimes phone or complete address) when setting up bill pay or wire transfers to ensure that you have the correct institution and they could contact someone if something goes wrong.